# SerializationException in BatchGetItem via API Gateway Proxy

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I want to call BatchGetItem to fetch multiple documents from simple table in DynamoDB using API Gateway json mapping template inside integration request.
Below template works for me when using **Query** action to get single item:

```
    {
    "TableName": "Test",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "ItemId = :i",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":i": {
            "N": "7"
        }
    }
```

When I change action to **BatchGetItem** and use following template I always get
  **"__type": "com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException"** with status 400.

Endpoint request body after transformations in log looks correct and is exactly the template below.
I also tested same request with nodejs sdk and it works perfect.

```
{
    RequestItems: {
        "Test": {
            Keys: [
                    { "ItemId": 7 }
            ],
            ProjectionExpression: "ItemId,Status,EventTime"
        }
    }
}
```

also tried this:

```
{
    RequestItems: {
        "Test": {
            Keys: [
                    { "ItemId": {"N":"7" }}
            ],
            ProjectionExpression: "ItemId,Status,EventTime"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW (in general) here is a recent new tutorial that seems to do everything you need (with 1 small exception that it is using regular `GetItem`, instead `BatchGetItem` as in this Question), and has more details/screenshots than I've seen in others: https://medium.com/@likhita507/using-api-gateway-to-get-data-from-dynamo-db-using-without-using-aws-lambda-e51434a4f5a0

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this by wrapping all properties and values as strings and setting key value type

```
{
    "RequestItems": {
        "Test": {
            "Keys": [
                    { "ItemId": {"N":"7" }}
            ],
            "ProjectionExpression": "ItemId,Status,EventTime"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, your original request was not valid JSON - strings need to be quoted. SerializationException means the input was not valid JSON.